# Object is possibly 'undefined'. During typescript array assignment and lookup

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, linter

When I try accessing a variable in an array using array assignment or lookup I get a typescript linting error saying that Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532). I try checking that all of the variables in the operation are not undefined yet that does not work. Here is my current code which creates a clone of a 2d array and sets a specific value to true.

```
let start: [number, number] = [0,0];

const visited: boolean[][] = Array.from<boolean[], boolean[]>({ length: rows }, 
                        () => Array<boolean>(cols).fill(false));

      
visited[start[0]][start[1]] = true;
```

The error specifically underlines "visited[start[0]]". Furthermore, this error occurs when I access an array defined in my react state.

Comment: please use `visited[start[0]]?.[start[1]] = true;`

Comment: TypeScript cannot guarantee that the indices `start[0]` and `start[1]` are valid, it warns you about the possibility of accessing an undefined element.
To resolve this, You can use the optional chaining operator (`?`) to handle potential undefined values.

Comment: The optional chaining operator does not work with assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is controlled with compiler flag [noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess). You seem to have this turned on (which I think is good). But that means that any time you access a value in an array, TypeScript will tell you that the element might be `undefined`, since TypeScript never knows the length of an array.

If you simply wish to access the value, you should use the *optional chaining operator* as suggested in the comments, `visited[start[0]]?.[start[1]]`, it will give you `undefined` if `visited[start[0]]` doesn't exist.

However if you wish to assign a value, you can't use that approach (contrary to what the comments say) since it would possibly end up in the statement `undefined = true` which is invalid. I'd use the following approach, where we ensure Typescript that `row` actually exist.

```js
const row = visited[start[0]]
if (row) {
  row[start[1]] = true
}
```

This might seem cumbersome but it's for the greater good (of type safety).
If you however want the simple approach, just disable `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` and your original code will work.